# Problem upgrading SphericalPlot3d to V11

Tags: graphics3d, textures, version-11

I am converting some code, which ran under V10.2, into V11. However, the results is different and undesirable.  Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
mI = Image[
  Graphics @@ GeoGraphics[
    GeoModel -> Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"],
    GeoProjection -> GeoProjectionData[][[46]]
    (* GallIsographic *)
  ]
];

SphericalPlot3D[
  1, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &),
  (* x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r *)
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[mI]],
  ViewVector -> {2 {Cos[6.392], Sin[6.392], 0}, {0, 0, 0} },
  Mesh -> False,
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> False
]
```

In V10.2, the output, as expected, looks like [image: Moon as Texture in V10.2]

However, in V11, I get the following distortion: [image: Moon as Texture in V11]

Note that the problem does not occur if the GeoProjection option is removed.

Is this a bug in V11, or am I misunderstanding how to texture?

Comment: Check what `GeoProjectionData[][[46]]` returns. Personally, I'd stick to `"Equirectangular"` for texturing: `mI = Image[GeoGraphics[GeoModel -> Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"], GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular"]]`.

Comment: On my Mac with v10.2 your code produces the error message "GeoGraphics::invgm: Entity[PlanetaryMoon,Moon] is not a valid GeoModel specification. >>"  along with a multi-colored, non-textured "sphere". The distorted output occurs in v10.3.1 and later.

Comment: To add to what JM said, this is somewhat of an abuse of `GeoProjectionData` that is not guaranteed to be stable between releases as projections are added and sorted differently. But, `GeoProjectionData["GallIsographic"]` is stable between releases, and `GeoProjection` can take the string `"GallIsographic"` directly (`GeoProjection -> "GallIsographic"` is equivalent to `GeoProjection -> GeoProjectionData@"GallIsographic"`) so I'd use that form.

Comment: Additionally, `Image[Graphics@@GeoGraphics[...]` is redundant as `Image` understands `GeoGraphics` in 10.2 and higher.

Comment: Are you aware of `EntityValue[Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"], "TexturedSurface"]`?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the commenters I now realize that the order of the values in GeoProjectionData has changed in V11, and that I should be directly using the projection name instead of indexing into the array.  Here is code that works correctly in V11:

```
Image[
  GeoGraphics[
    GeoModel -> Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"],
    GeoProjection -> "GallIsographic"
  ]
]
```

Thanks also for the advice about Graphics being redundant in V11.